# Autoforge Viewer canvas won't resize after open sibling container

Tags: reactjs, autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, react-class-based-component

I have 2 element rendering in a same parent element one of them is a parameter container that can open and close and other is forge viewer. At 876px width this parent element gets `flex-direction:column ;` . When i open parameters container and go below 876px and close the parameter container forge viewer canvas size wont resize and white blank space appears.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IpoPS.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MLcRK.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GCdps.png)

forgeView.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Script from 'react-load-script';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import { getActiveProject } from '../reducers/mainReducer';
import './forgeView.css';
import Message from './message';
import repo from '../Repository';
import { viewerCss, viewerJs } from './shared';
import ParametersContainer from './parametersContainer'
import './parametersContainer.css'

let Autodesk = null;

export class ForgeView extends Component {

    constructor(props){
      super(props);
        
      this.viewerDiv = React.createRef();
      this.viewer = null;
    }

    

    resizeViewer() {
        if (this.viewer && this.viewerDiv.current) {
            const container = this.viewerDiv.current;
            this.viewer.resize()
        }   
    }

    handleScriptLoad() {

        const options = repo.hasAccessToken() ?
                            { accessToken: repo.getAccessToken() } :
                            { env: 'Local' };

        Autodesk = window.Autodesk;

        const container = this.viewerDiv.current;
        this.viewer = new Autodesk.Viewing.GuiViewer3D(container);

        // uncomment this for Viewer debugging
        //this.viewer.debugEvents(true);

        Autodesk.Viewing.Initializer(options, this.handleViewerInit.bind(this));
        window.addEventListener("resize", this.resizeViewer.bind(this));
    }

    handleViewerInit() {
        const errorCode = this.viewer.start();
        if (errorCode)
            return;

        // orient camera in the same way as it's on the thumbnail
        // corresponding to ViewOrientationTypeEnum.kIsoTopRightViewOrientation
        const viewer = this.viewer;
        const forgeSpinner = document.getElementsByClassName("forge-spinner")[0]
        const image = forgeSpinner.children[1]
        image.src = "";
        this.viewer.addEventListener(Autodesk.Viewing.EXTENSION_LOADED_EVENT, (event) => {

            const viewCubeExtensionId = "Autodesk.ViewCubeUi";

            // this is not perfect, because the view transition is visible, so it's a place to improve someday
            if (event.extensionId === viewCubeExtensionId) {

                const viewCubeUI = event.target.getExtension(viewCubeExtensionId);
                viewCubeUI.setViewCube("front top right");

                viewer.removeEventListener(Autodesk.Viewing.EXTENSION_LOADED_EVENT);
            }

            const explodeExtension = viewer.getExtension('Autodesk.Explode');
            const sectionExtension = viewer.getExtension('Autodesk.Section');
            const modelExtension = viewer.getExtension('Autodesk.ModelStructure');
            const propertiesExtension = viewer.getExtension('Autodesk.PropertiesManager');

            explodeExtension.unload();
            sectionExtension.unload();
            modelExtension.unload();
            propertiesExtension.unload();

        });

        // skip loading of svf when there is no active project svf
        if (!this.props.activeProject.svf)
            return;

        Autodesk.Viewing.Document.load(
            this.getSvfUrl(), this.onDocumentLoadSuccess.bind(this), () => {}
        );
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.resizeViewer();
    }

    componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
        if (Autodesk && (this.props.activeProject.svf !== prevProps.activeProject.svf)) {
            Autodesk.Viewing.Document.load(
                this.getSvfUrl(), this.onDocumentLoadSuccess.bind(this), () => {}
            );
        }

        this.resizeViewer();

       
    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
        if (this.viewer) {
            this.viewer.finish();
            this.viewer = null;
            Autodesk.Viewing.shutdown();
        }

        window.removeEventListener("resize", this.resizeViewer.bind(this));
    }

    getSvfUrl() {
        return this.props.activeProject.svf + `/bubble.json`;
    }

    onDocumentLoadSuccess(viewerDocument) {
        const defaultModel = viewerDocument.getRoot().getDefaultGeometry();
        this.viewer.loadDocumentNode(viewerDocument, defaultModel).then(() => {
            this.viewer.fitToView();
        })
    }

    render() {

      return (
            <div className="modelContainer fullheight">
                <Message/>
              <div className="viewer" id="ForgeViewer">
                  <div ref={this.viewerDiv}></div>
                    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href={ viewerCss } />
                    <Script url={ viewerJs } onLoad={this.handleScriptLoad.bind(this)} />
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

I look up other similar questions but that didn't work for me.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see that you're already calling `viewer.resize` which should update the rendering context accordingly. If that's not working, I'd suggest to try the following:

- when you end up in the "broken" state where the viewer is not rendering the entire object, try opening the browser console, and type `NOP_VIEWER.resize()`; if that resolves the issue, it's possible that your code isn't calling the `viewer.resize` method at the right time
- are you perhaps using any animations when opening/closing the parameters UI? If so, try and disable them, or make sure that the `viewer.resize` is called after the animation is complete
- check the browser console to see if there are any errors or warnings that could be related to the incomplete rendering

Comment: Thanks `NOP_VIEWER.resize()` did solve my blank space problem but i don't know where to call `viewer.resize()` properly because i don't know the forge viewer api and this task assigned to me to solve problem but i can't solve it approximately 2 weeks. Also i am not using any animations for parameters UI

Comment: This is a React question, not a Viewer one. Basically, you'll need to call the resize method at the right time after React updates the DOM of your application.

Comment: i did a `console.log` in resizeViewer function it's working normally but when i open or close parameters UI it did not work properly. May be  my parametersContainer.js cause an issue ?

Comment: Yes, I think that could be.

Comment: Oh thanks for the answer by the way i solved the issue. I add `onClick()`  function to parameter button. When i click parameter button ,it's gonna resize every time when button click.

Comment: That's another way of doing that, yeah :) Good!